# Setup a single AWS load balancer for multiple .net core applications hosted as websites on a single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, .net-core, amazon-elb

Framework: .Net core 2.0

Hi everyone,

I have deployed let's say 3 applications on the same EC2 instance which are websites (front end angular js and 2 web apis for authentication and communication). How do I setup a single load balancer for catering requests for all of the 3 websites using HTTPS?

These websites communicate among each other for authentication and providing the required data between them.

The websites are deployed on the EC2 using hostnames on the IIS and they are accessible directly through the hostnames. Is there another/better way to deploy them instead of hostnames only?

[image: website deployed architecture]

Answer (score 1):

When setting up a load balancer, you would have to configure listeners for it, wherein you mention the ports through which you would want to access your application. And in the listeners you would have to mention target groups to which you would route traffic, based on hostnames / host headers.

So, here are the steps to follow.

1. Since all your traffic has to anyway go to the same instance, you would have to create one target group and register the instance that you have already created with traffic routed through the **80 port**.
2. Now, coming back to the ELB configuration, you would need to create a HTTP listener (port 80) that would have a default rule to redirect all traffic to HTTPS (port 443).
3. In the same ELB, create a HTTPS:443 listener, where (usually) you would have different listener rules depending on what are the hostnames of your sites in IIS. But just for simplicity, configure the default rule to route all traffic to the target group created in the step above (once we check if traffic is flowing right, we can change the configuration to improve security).

That's all!

With the right security group whitelisting, your traffic should flow into your instance through the ELB.

Congratulations! That should be enough...

... unless you want to make sure that ONLY the requests related to those sites flow into your instance, then, once you are sure that the traffic flow is right, you can create another listener rule in your ELB's HTTPS:443 listener, wherein you can configure the following setting:

IF Host Header is *frontend.website.com* OR *webapi1.website.com* OR *webapi2.website.com* THEN Forward to (target group created in Step 1)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I'm yet to try that out as this problem has been kept on the shelf. Will update here, once I try it out.